# How to add url access date to model5-names.bst (elsarticle.cls) for bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls, elsarticle

Header of my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

\begin{document}

My Paper

\bibliography{mybibfile01}

\end{document}
```

I need help to add the "URL accessed on date" for @online{} type bibliography entries.

I checked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270753/adding-retrieved-from-url-address-when-doi-is-absent-in-model5-names-bst-elsa), but this is not exactly what I need.

There are quite a few questions about adding "URL accessed on" dates, but I don't want to tinker with my current setup too much. I was wondering if this can be done by editing the model5-names.bst file. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Are you using biblatex or bibtex? The use of elsarticle class suggests bibtex, but there is no  @online entry type in standard bibtex classes, only in biblatex.

Comment: @EricMarsden.. I am a beginner at this. I think my document is using biblatex. The bibliography dropdown on my editor (Texstudio) has bibLatex checked. But I have not included any usepackage entries related to bibtex or biblatex. So far the online bibliography entries work along with everything else. However, I need to provide the "URL accessed on" for these online references and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with biblatex, but I believe you can achieve what you want by including an "urldate" field in your bibliography entry, or a "note" field with "accessed on YYY-MM-DD"; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404227/url-date-access-missing?rq=1 for example.

Comment: @EricMarsden Thanks :)  the "note" field worked for me .. Please make your comment as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (if not the most elegant) solution is to include the URL access date in a `note` field of the bibliography entry, with for example

```
note = {accessed on 2019-08-29}
```

This method should work with both bibtex and biblatex (for common style definitions).